# How to get current ion-slide index without a next button

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

i have question about hybrid mobile used ionic-cordova-angular. this question about problem ionic-slide-box without button next. i try to get current index when user swift page in slidebox.

how to get current index without i create button next slide.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you tried this?

```
function MyCtrl($scope, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate) {
  $scope.getCurrentIndex = function() {
    $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.currentIndex();
  }
}
```

http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicSlideBoxDelegate/

UPDATE:

To get the box index without a button you could use the callback onSlideChange of ionSlideBox directive:

HTML:

```
<ion-slide-box on-slide-changed="slideHasChanged($index)">
  <ion-slide>
    <div class="box blue"><h1>BLUE</h1></div>
  </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide>
    <div class="box yellow"><h1>YELLOW</h1></div>
  </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide>
    <div class="box pink"><h1>PINK</h1></div>
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slide-box>
```

Inside you controller:

```
$scope.slideHasChanged = function($index){
  alert('slideHasChanged $index=' + $index);
  if($index === 0){
    // first box
  }
};
```

[See this codepen demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OPrjBg)

Comment: yes I've tried it.

but this scope can show current index when i add button for trigger getCurrentIndex